# NSCompoundPredicate not filtering array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

To test out a restaurant searching app I included 4 test restaurants in a JSON file which populate a table view correctly with their corresponding properties. In 3 text fields I filter the array with a name, average entree price and rating, yet when I pass it to the method the filtered array logged is not filtered. I don't see anything wrong with my predicate code though, any ideas? Thank you!

```
- (void)searchRestaurantsWithName:(NSString *)name price:(int)price andRating:(int)rating  completion:(void (^)(NSArray *restaurants))completion {

NSMutableArray *restaurantsToFilter = [[RestaurantController sharedInstance].restaurants mutableCopy];

NSPredicate *namePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", name];
NSPredicate *pricePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"price < %i", price];
NSPredicate *ratingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rating > %i", rating];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[namePredicate, pricePredicate, ratingPredicate]];

NSArray *filteredArray = [restaurantsToFilter filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];

completion(filteredArray);

}
```

The method the button calls

```
- (void)filterArray {

[self searchRestaurantsWithName:self.nameTextField.text price:[self.priceTextField.text intValue]  andRating:[self.ratingTextField.text intValue] completion:^(NSArray *restaurants) {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"%@", restaurants);

}];
}
```

Comment: Casted too wide a net? You are using an or compound, so any restaurant matching at least one of the predicate will be in the result.

Comment: In other words, you want AND, not OR

Comment: Okay thank you, but now it's returning nothing at all, despite the fact that there are some compatible results.

Comment: Show the interface of a restaurant object please.

Comment: Try using only one of the three predicates to see if the lead to your desired results individually.

Comment: Your predicates seem fine. Just need to have a look at the JSON you are using. Add that to the question.